# Android emulator is incompatiable with Hyper-V in Android Studio (no Hyper-V installed)

Tags: windows-10, android-studio

Recently, I am using Android Studio to develop an app, but Android emulator can not work. It always displays the problem:

> Android emulator is incompatible with Hyper-V

However I have turned off Hyper-V in program feature, but it is still a problem. I've been stuck on this for whole week.

Would anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Try this command to remove Hyper-V `dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V-All`. And also this commad to disable `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`

Comment: i have tried both, it did not work at all, thanks your reply, :), there is no way i can solve it after i wasted two weeks, i have tried to use another emulator(visual studio emulator work with hyper-v) with android studio, it finally can work now, @Biswa

Comment: Android emulator compatibility with Hyper-V is currently in preview.  See this announcement for details: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/05/08/hyper-v-android-emulator-support/

Comment: Related post - [Can I run Android Studio (Android SDK emulator) in a Microsoft hyper-v virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35293574/465053)

Answer (score 7):

If you're running Windows 10 in an enterprise environment, there's a chance the problem could be new "virtualization based security" features in Windows.  If Device Guard or Credential Guard are enabled on your machine, that machine is using Hyper-V's hypervisor.

To check if that's the case, follow the instructions on [this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/access-protection/credential-guard/credential-guard-manage) or use the [Device Guard and Credential Guard hardware readiness tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53337).  Copied and pasted:

1. Click Start, type msinfo32.exe, and then click System Information.
2. Click System Summary.
3. Confirm that Credential Guard is shown next to Device Guard Security Services Running.

Typically, these features are enabled via Group Policy.  If that's actually the root cause of the issue, you'll need to work within your organization to opt out of those policies.

One final note -- I do not recommend disabling Intel VT-x (as suggested by Will P), as I believe HAXM (the hypervisor used by the Android emulator) requires VT-x.

Full disclosure -- I work at Microsoft on the Hyper-V team.

Comment: It seems that a fairly recent "Fast Ring" build of Windows 10 has changed the default behavior of virtualization based security, so that it's enabled by default, and rather difficult to turn off (haven't been able to permanently disable it). Since I need Intel HAXM to run Android Studio, I am in a perpetual state of disabling VBS, restarting, then using the emulator and eventually I'll need to do it again.

Comment: More up to date instructions for disabling VBS can be found in this blog post: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-Insider-Program/Windows-Defender-System-Guard-Making-a-leap-forward-in-platform/td-p/167303

Answer (score 0):

On an ASUS Z170M-PLUS motherboard and most likely other motherboards
Intel® Virtualization Technology needs to be disabled via the bios to stop Hyper V  services.
1. Reboot the machine.
2. Press delete or whatever key to enter the bios
3. Enter advanced mode and choose the advanced tab
4. Scroll down to Intel® Virtualization Technology and select disabled
5. Save and reboot the machine

[BIOS Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttR1U.png)