# Hyper-V is not being disabled. What to do?

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, hyper-v

I have disabled hyper-v in two ways, But system still detects a hypervisor.

[image: Image 1]

And then I saw this:

[image: Image 2]

Then I used this and restarted my computer.

[image: Image 3]

[image: Image 4]

Btw, I have enabled Virtualization in BIOS. I need to disable hyper-v for Gameloop Android Emulator.

Comment: Does [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1209266/android-emulator-is-incompatiable-with-hyper-v-in-android-studio-no-hyper-v-ins) help?

Comment: Disable it in the BIOS.

Comment: @DavidPostill that is not gonna help. It disables all Virtualization, so it won't work for Gameloop Android Emulator either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyper-V technology is not just used for Hyper-V. It is also used for Windows Sandbox and Docker. In order to free Hyper-V technology in windows, you will have to ensure that these are also disabled.

I still see Virtual Machine Platform enabled in your screenshot, and I'm pretty sure that needs to be disabled too.

Comment: Not only the obvious settings but also “Virtualization-based Security”. Which sometimes cannot be disabled.

Comment: Yes, it worked. But isn't it necessary for running wsl2?

Comment: Not sure. I don't use WSL2 myself, so I can't test it, but if WSL2 doesn't work after disabling it, and it starts working after enabling it again, you then have your answer. It is up to you to decide what you want more. WSL or that android emulator.